# When echoing with bash some values are not copied

Tags: bash, ubuntu

I want to echo all of this into the file:

```
echo "server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  mydomain.com;
    root         /srv/www/clients/;

    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    charset utf-8;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    access_log off;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/finance-error.log error;

    sendfile off;

    client_max_body_size 100m;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_intercept_errors off;
        fastcgi_buffer_size 16k;
        fastcgi_buffers 4 16k;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }

 }" >> default
```

But all of those values that contain a dollar sign (like $query_string; or $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;) are removed. Is it possible somehow to escape that so that all of these values would also persist to the file?

Comment: Use single quotes instead of double quotes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should either use single quotes to prevent parameter expansion, or you could use a here-doc:

```
cat <<'EOF' > default
$query_string
$document_root
$fastcgi_script_name
EOF
```

(or `>> default`, if you want to append). Notice how `'EOF'` is quoted to prevent parameter expansion.

Comment: And use `<<-` for the indented variety :-)

Comment: @RanyAlbegWein I actually thought about mentionting that, but this swallows *all* leading tabs. Works neatly with space indented code, though!

Comment: Oh, didn't know about that. Thanks :-) Well, maybe a `cat <<- EOF | sed "s/$'\t'/4-spaces/g" >> default` will be fine for OP.